# How do we let users know if a dashboard shows the entities’ lifetime activity or activity during the selected date range?

Tags: labels, dashboard, timeline

I am currently designing a dashboard that displays data related to entities (e.g., campaigns, ads, ad groups). **My challenge is to effectively communicate whether the data presented pertains to the lifetime performance of entities created during the selected date range or if it represents activity that occurred during the selected date range.**
To clarify further, here's the key distinction: Some pages of the dashboard present information about entities created during the selected date range, while other pages show activity data during the selected date range for all entities, regardless of when they were created.

As users navigate through the dashboard, it's critical that they immediately grasp this distinction to interpret the data correctly. Since there is no direct mode-switching option, we must rely on visual and textual cues to convey this context.

Therefore, what are the most effective user experience design strategies, visual cues, and labeling approaches for clearly communicating whether a dashboard page displays data for entities created during the selected date range or activity during the selected date range?

I appreciate any insights, examples, or articles you can share. Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify what a "dashboard page" is, and how the user interacts with it? Would you have a screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

The term dashboard has been so overused to refer to anything that seems to combine more than one graph together on a single page, when in fact we should be more careful about the use of the word and the problem it was designed to solve.

What most people commonly refer to as a dashboard consists of a single page that includes one or more modules that display data in a number of different formats, arranged in a way that shows some relationship between the datasets. Often there are also some interactive elements that allow the user to filter or change the view of one or more datasets.

So the best answer to the question is to understand the relationship between the different datasets in your dashboard and work out what makes more sense based on how the information will be used.